# DB2, when trying to calculate difference between provided and stored timestamp I get an error 'The invocation of function is ambiquious'

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

This is my sql string from which I prepare statement:

```
SELECT (DAYS(?) - DAYS(FROM)) * 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(?) -
           MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(FROM)) AS FROM_DIFF,
       (DAYS(?) - DAYS(TO)) * 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(?) - 
           MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TO)) AS TO_DIFF
FROM CALENDAR.EVENTS WHERE ID = ?
```

fill values with the following code:

```
        ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(...));
        ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(...));
        ps.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(...));
        ps.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(...));
        ps.setInt(5, ...);
```

And get an exception:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
>   SQLCODE=-245, SQLSTATE=428F5, SQLERRMC=DAYS;1, DRIVER=4.16.53

When I run it directly from SQL browser it run flawlessly:

```
SELECT 
    (DAYS('2015-05-05 00:00:00.0') - DAYS(FROM)) * 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS('2015-05-05 00:00:00.0') - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(FROM)) AS FROM_DIFF,
    (DAYS('2015-05-05 00:00:00.0') - DAYS(TO)) * 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS('2015-05-05 00:00:00.0') - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TO)) AS TO_DIFF  
FROM CALENDAR.EVENTS WHERE ID = 1055;
```

Where is a mistake?

Thank you.

P.S. Formula how to calculate time difference is taken from this article:
[DB2 Basics: Fun with Dates and Times](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several overloaded versions of the `DAYS()` function, accepting parameters with different data types: `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, and `VARCHAR`. When you use an untyped parameter marker (`DAYS(?)`) the query compiler is unable to determine which version of the function to use in the query.

You can specify the parameter data type explicitly for compilation: `DAYS(CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP))`. Alternatively, if you are using a recent DB2 for LUW version (9.7 and higher) you can set the DB2 registry variable:

```
db2set DB2_DEFERRED_PREPARE_SEMANTICS=YES
```

to tell the compiler that it should defer the PREPARE call until the query execution time, when parameter data types are already known.

Comment: Thank you, first option is preferable because I not always have access to DB