# How can I distinguish in Primefaces's p:dialog when it closed by clicking or by hide() function?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using with the Primefaces's [`<p:dialog>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213857/db2-when-trying-to-calculate-difference-between-provided-and-stored-timestamp-i) the following code:

```
<p:ajax event="close" oncomplete="dialogClosed();"/>
```

The problem that `dialogClosed();` invoked when I close dialog by clicking X and when I close by using javascript in the following way `PF('<widget-name>).hide()`

Is it possible to know in `dialogClosed()` how it closed?

P.S. I will try to create global variable which will be used as a flag to indicate how it was called, but looking for a more straightforward solution if it possible.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a more simple solution than this (and it already is simple in my opinion). Overriding the PF javascript implementation is another solution, but not simple.

Comment: Just use a variable as flag. `closedWithHide=true;PF('<widget-name>).hide();`

Comment: @XtremeBiker. I already use this solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Anatoly you're welcome. I think it's a nice solution for a concrete use case, however it could be problematic for the whole application.